# Getting Error "No Java runtime present", how do I solve it?

Tags: java

I wanted to check if I had Java installed, so I typed:

```
java -version
```

Then I got the following response

```
No Java runtime present, requesting install.
```

In addition to the above response, the following dialogue box also showed.
[image]

Does this mean I am only missing the JDK but I have the other components needed to use Java or do I download Java from scratch?

If it is just the JDK, can I use brew to download?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means Java is NOT installed in your system, download from Oracle site or use brew to install.

Just to clarify you're trying to get Java version but it couldn't find. so asking you to install.

Oracle:

https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-jdk15-downloads.html

Homebrew:

The below formula could be used,

https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/openjdk